# AutoFill function and methods not working in unity 5.3.5

Tags: c#, unity, monodevelop

I opened one of c# code in my projects, and edited something in the code, and I noticed that MonoDevelop no longer gives auto filling of function and method options.

Below is the screen shot of the code.When I type debug,its not showing the dropdown with list of function and methods.

[image]

Iam using 5.3.5 (64 bit)Personal and windows 8.

Can anybody help me sorting this issue.

When I open a c# code. its showing the namespace in redcolor
[image]

this is how the code structure looks

Answer (score 1):

Open C# project by right click on Project tab. It opens the project solution file not just one script.
[image]

---

**Suggestion:**

Get [visual studio community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx). After installation, go to (in Unity) Edit>>Preferences>>External Tools. Select VS instead of MonoDevelop.

[image]

Comment: I opened the same.But still its not working for me

Comment: if you are using any version control system try committing before editing.

Comment: no,Iam not using

Comment: I am using Windows 8.Is there any problem with OS versions?

Comment: not an OS issue.

you can always use visual studio community. never had any issue after using VS.

Comment: whether I need to install Windows store .net scripting backend from the UnityDownloadAssistant ?Will it be a solution?

Comment: Not related to that. Use visual studio community edition. It's free and hassle free. Works all the time.

Comment: How to work on it.Whether I need to install any plugins?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx

Comment: Once i add this,auto correction will be working?

Comment: You have to install it and check edit on answer how to integrate. Works fine for me. Had issues with monodevelop as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41852/discussion-between-user1509674-and-sp).